# Reference generated code in Java

Tags: java, android, android-contentprovider, generated-code

I'm creating an android application. I'm using [schematic](https://github.com/SimonVT/schematic) to generate a content provider.

I understand that the actual code used by the application is generated out of the classes I create. Based on that, I'd like to know what problems I will face if I reference the generated code in the source code.

The code I'm using is the following:

```
package com.example.movies.data;

@Database(
  version = MovieDatabase.VERSION,
  packageName = "com.example.movies.provider"
)
public class MovieDatabase {
  public static final int VERSION = 1;

  @Table(MovieColumns.class)
  public static final String MOVIE = "movie";   

  // Some more tables here

  @OnUpgrade
  public static void onUpgrade(Context context, SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("drop table if exists " + MOVIE);

    // The next SQL statement is generated out of the current class
    db.execSQL(com.example.movies.provider.MovieDatabase.MOVIE);
  }
}
```

The generated code is next:

```
package com.example.movies.provider;

public class MovieDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
  private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

  // The next statement is the one I use in the source code
  public static final String MOVIE = "CREATE TABLE movie ("
  + MovieColumns._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
  + MovieColumns.TITLE + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
  + MovieColumns.SYNOPSIS + " TEXT,"
  + MovieColumns.POSTER_URL + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
  + MovieColumns.RELEASE_DATE + " INTEGER NOT NULL,"
  + MovieColumns.RATING + " REAL)";

  // Some other SQL statements and functions

  // The next function is generated out of onUpgrade 
  // in the source class MovieDatabase
  @Override
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    com.example.movies.data.MovieDatabase.onUpgrade(context, db, oldVersion, newVersion);
  }
}
```

As you can see, I need the SQL statements generated by the source code, and the idea of using the mentioned library is to avoid all the boilerplate code.

Are there other alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

Slightly better approach would be:

```
  @OnUpgrade
  public static void onUpgrade(Context context, SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("drop table if exists " + MOVIE);

    // The next SQL statement is generated out of the current class
    com.example.movies.provider.MovieDatabase.getInstance(context).onCreate(db);
  }
```

At least you do not need to specify each table.

> Based on that, I'd like to know what problems I will face if I reference the generated code in the source code.

I would say no real problems.

The only noticeable thing is that Android Studio will highlight this as compilation error until class is generated (during the first build).